# Can I undo a merge if I hadn't committed the code before it?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-bash

What I did:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

Made several changes to this branch. Then:

```
git merge oldbranch
```

None of the changes to the `newbranch` had been committed so I can't roll back. And now none of those changes have been applied, there's only code from the `oldbranch`. Is there a way to undo the merge? Also how should I go about doing this the next time or what did I do wrong? Please help.

What I tried:
I had used `git stash` on the `newbranch` before the merge so I tried using `git apply` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Edit: I think also used gut stash at the wrong time or something, because the only change I can see is one single line, I am brand new to git.

Comment: What you did wrong is simple: don't perform a merge when you have uncommitted changes. Commit them somewhere, or [use "git stash" to store them temporarily](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Comment: In current versions of Git, `git merge` would typically refuse to start if you had made any changes. There's an exception for fast-forward operations though. What version of Git are you using? What was the output of the `git merge` command?

Comment: @IMSoP I had used git stash, and then I tried using git apply, should I use a different command to apply these changes?

Comment: If you stashed your changes, then read the manual page I linked you to, it tells you all the commands you can do. Also, next time you ask a question like this, don't leave out details like that - it makes the whole question completely different!

Comment: @IMSoP I edited the question. Thank you. I'll try that.

Comment: You don't want `git apply`, you want `git stash pop`.

Comment: My git version is 2.28.windows.1. As for the output it was just all the insertions and deletions in the files that showed up

Answer (score 0):

If you have a commit you do not need, then you can use [git revert](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert) in order to roll back. In your case, if you have things in the stash, it should not be a problem. However, the cleanest solution would be to run

```
git log
```

find the last commit hash that's still needed, then run

```
git checkout <thehash>
git branch somenewbranch
git checkout somenewbranch
```

then switch back to your branch, do the revert, load back the stash, checkout somenewbranch and run

```
git diff somenewbranch newbranch
```

You will see the difference, apply what's needed for somenewbranch and you should be okay with working with the new branch.